# How to create a UITableview cell without using dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, uitableview

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    Cell *cell = (ChannelViewTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];


    NSString *channelName;
    channelName= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Enter Channel %ld Name", (long)indexPath.row+1];
    indexPathRow= indexPath.row+1;
    return cell;

}
```

Comment: Tell me the reason why  you want to create without that?

Comment: Why don't you want to use dequeue? That's optimization. If you encounter issue, it's maybe because you do something wrong. Explain, and we can help appropriately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create one by using

```
[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:<#(UITableViewCellStyle)#> reuseIdentifier:<#(nullable NSString *)#>]
```

but as already said by @MuraliMohan and @Larme we dequee to improve performance by avoiding creation of unecessary cells.

The way it is done is simple, lets assume that you have 100 cells to display. As the device screen is too small for all that you will at most be displaying 15 cell at a time to the user, without dequeing you will be generating 100 cells and displaying 15. What dequeing does is when a cell goes off screen the OS will reuse it for the next cell to display so instead of 100 you will have only 16 cells on memory.

Basically, just keep dequeing but if you want try generating a lot of cells in a test app without dequeing to see how performance decreases ;)

Comment: Thanks, I know it will effect on performance.But i need only 6 cell.

Comment: I believe that even with only 6 it is recommended to deque as the OS will take care of creating the cells if no one is available and you don't lose or gain anything by dequeing, in the end it is up to you what to use.

Comment: hmmmmm :) :) :)

Answer (score 0):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    TableViewCell *cell = (TableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"TableViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.NumberLabel.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Enter Channel %ld Name", (long)indexPath.row+1];
    cell.Name.tag = indexPath.row;

    NSString *dicKey = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)indexPath.row];

    if (self.cellTextFiledValues[dicKey])
        cell.channelName.text = self.cellTextFiledValues[dicKey];
    else
        cell.channelName.text = @"";

    cell.selectionStyle =NO;
    return cell;
}

- (void)resetTableview{

    self.cellTextFiledValues = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [self.channelViewTableView reloadData];
}
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    totalChannelCount =[self.datacount.text intValue];
    NSString *dicKey = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)textField.tag];
    [self.cellTextFiledValues setObject:textField.text forKey:dicKey];
    [self.myTableview reloadData];


}
```